# How to access rails request object in rspec integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1, integration-testing

In Rails 3.2.13, subdomain is provided by default. As such, I want to test my application such that when a merchant signs up, he goes by default to root_url with subdomain 'merchant' i.e. https://merchant.lvh.me:3000. However, I am having trouble testing the same in RSpec. My test looks like this:

```
  describe "Sign in" do
    before { visit signup_path }
    let(:submit) { "Sign up" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
        it "should not create a user" do
            expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
        end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
        before do
            fill_in "Email", with: "user@gmail.com"
            fill_in "Password", with: "securepassword"
        end

        describe "as a merchant" do
            before { choose("Merchant") }

            it "should create a merchant user" do
                expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
            end

            describe "after creating the merchant user" do
                before do
            click_button submit
            request = ActionController::TestRequest.new(:host => "lvh.me:3000")
         end
                let(:merchant) { User.find_by_email('user@gmail.com') }

                expect (request.subdomain).to eq('merchant')
                it { should have_selector 'div.alert.alert-success', text: "Welcome to App!" }
                it { should have_link "Sign out", href: signout_path }
                it { should_not have_link "Sign in", href: signin_path }
                it { should have_content merchant.email }
          it { should have_selector "title", text: full_title(merchant.email) }
            end
        end

        describe "as a user" do
            before do
          choose("User")
          request = ActionController::TestRequest.new(:host => "lvh.me:3000")
        end

            it "should create a normal user" do
                expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
            end

            describe "after creating the normal user" do
                before { click_button submit }
                let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@gmail.com') }

                expect (request.subdomain).to eq('user')
                it { should have_selector 'div.alert.alert-success', text: "Welcome to App!" }
                it { should have_link "Sign out", href: signout_path }
                it { should_not have_link "Sign in", href: signin_path }
          it { should have_content user.email }
          it { should have_selector "title", text: full_title(user.email) }
            end
        end
    end
  end
```

Error is:

```
19:58:54 - INFO - Guard::RSpec is running, with RSpec 2!
19:58:54 - INFO - Running all specs
Running tests with args ["--drb", "-f", "progress", "-r", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-rspec-1.2.1/lib/guard/rspec/formatters/notification_rspec.rb", "-f", "Guard::RSpec::Formatter::NotificationRSpec", "--out", "/dev/null", "--failure-exit-code", "2", "spec"]...
Exception encountered: #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `request' for #<Class:0x007fe0d8058848>>
backtrace:
/home/app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:46:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
/home/app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:39:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
/home/app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
/home/app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
/home/app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `module_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:238:in `subclass'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:224:in `describe'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
/home/app/spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `run_tests'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `fork'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-0.9.2/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in `perform'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'
Done.
```

I tried to print request object to see if anything is there, but its blank. How to access request object in RSpec integration test or is integration test the right place to test for this kind of behavior? Please suggest.

**Edit: More Information** My data model consists of only single user table where all by default are normal users. However, some are merchants also. Now, when someone signs-in as a user (distinguished using radio button in sign-in form), he should be redirected to user.lvh.me and if he signs-in as a merchant, he should be redirected to merchant.lvh.me. This is what I am trying to test in my integration tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mock a request using

```
ActionController::TestRequest.new()
```

for example

```
request = ActionController::TestRequest.new(:host => test_domain)
```

Comment: Hi, I did as you suggested, but still getting the same error. Please see the logs I have included in the question itself.

Comment: As I don't see any more answers coming and this is the closest someone has gone to, i am accepting it. But if someone can come with a better explanation why i can't get request in integration tests, would accept that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really clear what behaviour you are trying to test here.

It seems that you have a sign up form where merchants can sign up. Once they have signed up they should get their own subdomain ( merchant1.lvh.me, merchant2.lvh.me). Is that right?

If that is right, then it looks like you are trying to test that the sub-domain for the sign up **request** should be set. I don't think thats how it works - the client is in control of the domain that the request is made to not the server. I suspect what you want to do is perform a redirect after successful signup to the appropriate subdomian. Thus you want to test that the **response** is redirecting to the subdomain.

Comment: Hi @Perryn Fowler, I have updated the question. Actually there are two class of users - user & merchant. If someone sign-in as a user, he should be redirected to user.lvh.me and if he sign-in as a merchant (distinguishing using radio button in sign-in form), he should be redirected to merchant.lvh.me. This is what I am trying to test in my integration tests.